# Spring-instrument and auto injection in new object

Tags: java, spring, hashmap, code-injection

I have spring 3.1 application. And I Have spring-instrument java agent, I have configurable class:

```
@Configurable
public class WeavingClass {

    @Resource
    @Getter
    private ApplicationContext ac;

    public WeavingClass()
    {

    }

}
```

And Have unit test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes={WebBackendContextConfig.class})
@Slf4j
public class TestWeavingInjection extends TestCase {

    @Test
    public void isInjectedTest()
    {
        WeavingClass wc = new WeavingClass();
        assertNotNull(wc.getAc());
    }
}
```

And Have:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value={"classpath:META-INF/conf/liteicms-backend.properties"})
@ComponentScan(value={"ru.icb.liteicms.backend.service", "ru.icb.liteicms.domain", "ru.icb.liteicms.backend.domain.contentpage.wrappers"})
@EnableSpringConfigured
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class WebBackendContextConfig {

}
```

I run my test with  -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
My test working without errors.

But if I add this:

```
private HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>> builderMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, Class<?>>()
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    {
    put(String.class, WeavingClass.class);
    }
};
```

My test has broken.

Comment: Are you passing the command line arguments to the jvm running the junit test to start the instrumentation aguent something like -javaagent:org.springframework.instrument-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Yes of course. Test will be working if I delete part with hashmap init.

Comment: Where did you put the `HashMap` stuff, and are you sure about all the nested blocks there?

Comment: Anywhere in my code. For example in test.

Answer (score 2):

Injection on `new`-created objects (rather than managed beans) is only possible with compile- or load-time weaving, not with the run-time proxies that Spring uses by default.

You will need to configure one of an AspectJ weaver, `<context:load-time-weaver>`, or start the JVM with command-line options to enable the `InstrumentationSavingAgent`.

[Details from the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw)